# why is new Array slow?

Tags: javascript, arrays, benchmarking, profile

when comparing the operation

```
var fat_cats = cats.slice()
```

to

```
var fat_cats = new Array(cats.length)
```

the performance differences are confusing.

In firefox and chrome `new Array` is slower (when it should be faster, it's just allocating an empty array and not doing iteration over it)

Where as in IE8 `new Array` is faster (which is just confusing)

Any explanation appreciated.

[benchmark](http://jsperf.com/mapclone/6)

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi either way your overwriting the array with those values

Comment: I don't think the test case is valid, as you're introducing some cache locality issues. I think you should stick to `j[i] = a[i] / 255;` at all times, instead of switching between it and `j[i] = j[i] / 255;`, which might (naturally?) be faster due to cache locality. EDIT - changed the test case to be more valid, still same results: http://jsperf.com/mapclone/8

Comment: In your "Clone empty and loop" benchmark you have `var j = new Array(a.Length)` instead of `a.length` so `j` is getting `var j = new Array(undefined)`. If you fix that it's still slower, but by a much smaller margin. [yours](http://jsperf.com/mapclone/6) vs [bugfix](http://jsperf.com/mapclone/13)

Comment: It seems to be an optimization for large arrays in the V8 source. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out by looking at [the source code](http://code.google.com/searchframe#W9JxUuHYyMg/trunk/src/array.js&q=slice%20package:http://v8%5C.googlecode%5C.com&ct=rc&cd=9&sq=) for V8's array functions.

If an array has more than 1000 elements and `.slice` is called, a function called `SmartSlice` is used, verses the `SimpleSlice` function used otherwise.

`SimpleSlice` is implemented as a for loop copy (exactly the same as the code in the array copy test case). `SmartSlice`, on the other hand, uses sparse arrays to represent the data.

In [a test case](http://jsperf.com/mapclone/12) where the number of elements is dropped from 10,000 to below 1000, they are exactly the same performance (within the margin of error), whereas in [a better-controlled test case](http://jsperf.com/mapclone/11) with fewer variation and more than 1000 elements, the SmartSlice method is ~36% faster than the naïve copy.

---

While this explains the V8 side of things perfectly, I do not know why Firefox is also slower on new arrays than sliced arrays, even at smaller sizes - unless they have a similar optimization in place (perhaps for all slice functions).

EDIT

This kept bugging me, so I downloaded the Firefox source and checked out `js/src/jsarray.cpp!array_slice`, and Firefox does have a similar optimization: the result of `.slice` is a `DenseCopiedArray` or `DenseAllocatedArray`, which is apparently similar to the V8 sparse array.

Comment: `.slice()` is used to copy an array, so it would create a new array.

Comment: No, that's my point. I think it doesn't create a new array until the first write, so they're just aliases for the same object until then?

Comment: Good work with the global variable :) It's surprising that this makes such a big difference.

Comment: @RobW I don't think it's COW actually, I'm doing more tests. But your writes aren't making a difference since they're after the writing anyway. It would have to be done after the slice and before anything else.

Comment: @Rob W: What's your point? The whole array will have been copied by then anyway.

Comment: @NiklasB. my last jsperf (#10) splices a but reads from z which is manually copied from a.

Comment: @Mahmoud: Heh, must have missed that.

Comment: OK, I figured it out and updated my reply. What the heck is an interval array? Google code search is breaking for me :(