# 8 millions iterations over 700ms in JS is okay? How to speed up?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a game and initializing a map 2000 x 4000 blocks.
It runs only once onLoad and takes ~700ms. How can I speed it up? Other logic depends on this map.
Here is the code:

```
var start = new Date();
var g = {};
g.world = { h:2000, w:4000, cellInfo: [] };
var i, j,
    world = g.world,
    hlim = world.h,
    wlim = world.w,
    cellInfo = world.cellInfo;
for ( i = hlim; i; i--) {
    cellInfo[i] = [];
    for (j = wlim; j; j--) {
        cellInfo[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
g.world.cellInfo = cellInfo;
alert(new Date() - start);​
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NSX9z/

Comment: This gives 200ms for me http://jsfiddle.net/NSX9z/1/

Comment: This gives less than 100ms for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/NSX9z/3/

Comment: another (premature) optimization might be to make cellInfo[i] a local var, so it isn't looked up 4000 times in the inner loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of options for you:

#### Lazy init

Your best bet for speeding it up is to use lazy initialization instead. E.g., instead of initializing all 8 million slots, have the code the relies on them handle it if they're not there. E.g., to get a cell

```
function getCell(x, y) {
    var row, cell;

    row = cellInfo[x];
    if (!row) {
        row = cellInfo[x] = [];
    }

    cell = row[y];
    if (typeof cell === "undefined") {
        cell = row[y] = 1; // 1 appears to be the default value
    }

    return cell;
}
```

...and similar for `setCell`. That spreads out the init. Of course, it means things are slightly slower, though it's unlikely to be a perceptible difference.

#### Array cloning

If you don't do that, another option is to create the 4,000-slot array once, then clone it rather than creating it by hand, in hopes that doing the work inside the JavaScript engine is faster than doing the actual loop yourself:

```
// ...
var the4k = [];
// ...build it...
// Now use it for one row and clone it for the others
cellInfo[hlim] = the4k;
for ( i = hlim - 1; i; i--) {
    cellInfo[i] = the4k.slice(0);
}
```

Array cloning [speeds things up *dramatically*](http://jsfiddle.net/NSX9z/4/) for me, Chrome goes from ~780ms to ~130ms, IE9 from ~530ms to ~50ms.

The other issue to consider is that on IE8 and earlier, the "slow script warning" isn't based on *time*, but on *number of operations*. Your fiddle gives me the slow script warning on IE8. Mine doesn't.

IE8 argues for lazy-init, though, as it takes nearly **9 seconds** to run even my version of the fiddle.

Comment: Btw, this isn't magic, it just moves the real work [until first writes are done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10470388/995876). You will then pay the same performance as the op is paying upfront right now. To gain real performance, typed arrays should probably be used.

Comment: @Esailija: Interesting info. Certainly based on that answer that would account for some of the speed increase on Chrome. I wouldn't bet on that being the case in IE9. But any time I can move a loop out of the JavaScript userland into the engine's internals, I call that a win. :-) And IE8 seems to count the `slice` as one operation rather than 4,000-20,000, so...

Comment: <del>Interesting to note that with typed array cloning, it runs in 3ms for me http://jsfiddle.net/NSX9z/6/ in google chrome.</del> Nevermind, `subarray` is not the same as slice

Comment: @Esailija: And 7 for me. A *bit* of an advance over 780ms for the original or 130 for untyped array cloning. **Nice**. Of course, typed arrays are quite new and not even in IE9 (though I note that they seem to be in the latest Firefox and Opera!).

Comment: Thank you so much T.J! I had an idea, that i can somehow use data that was already generated, but couldn't realize how. Thank you Esailija for that exciting mark about typed arrays!