# How can I tell Typescript a method accepts any number of arguments which using a rest argument?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that's used a lot, so I want to optimize it as much as possible. I benchmarked it and with Babel, the second one is faster by ~10%:

```
class EventEmitter {
  emit(eventName: string, ...args: any[]) {
    const callbacks = this._callbacks[eventName];
    if (callbacks) {
      for (const cb of callbacks) {
        cb(...args);
      }
    }
  }
}

class EventEmitter {
  emit(eventName: string) {
    const callbacks = this._callbacks[eventName];
    if (callbacks) {
      for (const cb of callbacks) {
        cb(...Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the second case, I still need Typescript to know that `emit` accepts a variable number of arguments. What's the Typescript syntax for casting `emit` to `(eventName: string, ...args: any[]) => void`? If I add `...args: any[]` without using it, Babel still adds it to the transpiled version.

Comment: It seems counter-intuitive to me that the first function is slower than the second, based solely on the way the rest of the function arguments are obtained. Did you look at the transpiled code to see what it is converted to?

Comment: I decided to check what the generated code looks like in the [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRly7m). When targeting ES5, the first one generates code that creates a new array and appends the remaining args to it, while the second one which is using Array.slice is faster due to optimizations done with Array.slice, where it creates a "sparse array", rather than a copy of the new array. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10470388/2089675). Not sure how the performace will change when targeting ES6+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an overload (or external signature):

```
class EventEmitter {
  emit(eventName: string, ...args: any[]): void;
  emit(eventName: string) {
    const callbacks = this._callbacks[eventName];
    if (callbacks) {
      for (const cb of callbacks) {
        cb(...Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More in-depth answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73732162/how-to-implemented-a-function-returning-with-typemap-return/73733862#73733862) from an earlier post.